# ¿Cómo puedo pasar datos de python a html?

Tags: html, python, flask

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación web en python con el microframework. en una de las páginas debo traerme datos de mysql y mostrarlos en tablas y gráficos. Los datos desde mysql a python sé traerlos pero desde python a html no. Gracias.

Comment: Lo siento Alfonso, pero tu pregunta es demasiado amplia o poco definida. Respondemos dudas especificas o fallos con más información aportada. Esta pregunta abre un debate de opinión y hay mucha documentacion en internet sobre el tema.

Answer (score 1):

Suponiendo que trabajes con flask solo tienes que pasar la variable que contiene los datos que deseas imprimir en el render_template, con esto podrás acceder a ella con {{nombreVariable}}

```
@app.route('/')
def get_data():
    name = 'Alfonso'
    return render_template('index.html', name = name)
```

Después en el html solo tienes que hacer algo así.

```
<html>
  <body>
    <h1>name = {{name}}</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```